# Why does this JSON decoding crash my app?

Tags: swift, decodable

I have this function that is triggered by keyboard input, if the input is correct the application proceeds correctly; if not the application essentially freezes and the keyboard input cannot be changed (requires restart).

**This is what calls the function:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    makeGetCall()
    repeat{
        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
    }while !done
```

**Function Being Called:**

```
func makeGetCall() {
    let jsonUrlString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + ",us&appid=f0d10597634568abee813f68138452fd&units=imperial"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return

    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        do {

            self.document = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDocument.self, from: data)
            self.done = true

            print(self.document!)
            print("========================INIT===============================")
            print(self.document?.main?.temp! ?? "No temp")
            print(self.document?.name! ?? "No temp")
            print(self.document?.weather![0].description ?? "No info")
            print(self.document?.wind?.speed ?? "No wind")
            print("==========================END===============================")
            print(self.document?.weather![0].main ?? "No main info")
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }


        }.resume()
}
```

Any ideas why this happening?

**This is the error message that is displayed in the console:**

> "Error serializing json: typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "cod", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil)"

**WeatherDocument**

```
struct WeatherDocument: Decodable {
let coord: Coordinates?
let weather: [Weather]?
let base: String?
let main: Main?
let visibility: Double?
let wind: Wind?
let clouds: Clouds?
let dt: Double?
let sys: Sys?
let id: Double?
let name: String?
let cod: Double?
}
```

**Now the application does a breakpoint at the following statements I have made:**

```
    let tempe = (self.document?.main?.temp!)!
    let humiditye = (self.document?.main?.humidity!)!
    let pressurePow = (self.document?.main?.pressure!)! * 0.295300 * 0.10

    let tempeMax = (self.document?.main?.temp_max!)! - 273.15
    let tempeMin = (self.document?.main?.temp_min!)! - 273.15
    //let clouding = (self.precip?.threeHours!)!
    let name = (self.document?.name!)!
```

Why does the completion handler have a problem with this?

Comment: post full context

Comment: seems you have a coding proeblem post your model **WeatherDocument** along with the json

Comment: I have posted the WeatherDocument

Comment: can you share the url so we can see it's response , it seems it's dark sky api

Comment: The API is OpenWeatherMap, have a look at the changes I've made

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The value for key `cod` in the root object is `String`, not `Double`. And the `repeat - while` loop is horrible. Don't do that. That's the reason of the freeze by the way. Learn to handle **a**synchronous data processing.

Comment: What can use instead of the repeat loop?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. The error clearly states that the type of `cod` is String. And you can declare all struct members as non-optional. Openweathermap sends reliable data. There are only a few values (for example `Rain` in the forecast API) which are optional

   ```
   let cod : String
   ```
2. **Never** use such a repeat loop. You block the thread. Use a completion handler. And it's highly recommended to use `URLComponents` which adds percent encoding implicitly.

   ```
   var city = "New York,us"
   let apiKey = <your api key>

   ...

   func makeGetCall(completion: @escaping (WeatherDocument?, Error?)->Void) {
       var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather")!
       let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: city),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "appid", value: apiKey),
                         URLQueryItem(name: "units", value: "imperial")]

       guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
           print("Error: cannot create URL")
           return
       }

       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
           guard let data = data else {
               print("Error: did not receive data")
               completion(nil, error!)
           }
           do {

               let document = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherDocument.self, from: data)

               print(document)
               print("========================INIT===============================")
               print(document.main.temp) // main and temp can be non-optional
               print(document.name) // name can be non-optional
               print(document.weather[0].description) // weather and description can be non-optional
               print(document.wind.speed) // wind and speed can be non-optional
               print("==========================END===============================")
               print(document.weather[0].main) // weather and main can be non-optional
               completion(document, nil)
           } catch {
               print("Error serializing json:", error)
               completion(nil, error)
           }


       }.resume()
   }
   ```

   and call it

   ```
   makeGetCall() { doc, error in
       if let doc = doc {
          self.document = doc
       } else {
         print(error!)
       }
   }
   ```

PS: You are mixing up the *forecast* and the *weather* API. Your struct belongs to the forecast API – where `cod` is actually `Int` – but the code (and the decoding error) belongs to weather API. The struct in the question will never work with this code / URL.

Comment: The completion handler now causes the Xcode to breakpoint at (see question)

Comment: **Please read the PS**. That's the reason. And please use my code without all the `!` and `?` and declare the struct members as non-optional (remove the question marks).

Comment: Any reason I am getting this error as well? Use of unresolved identifier 'error'

Comment: Change the closure parameters to usual `(data, response, error)`

Comment: Any reason why it takes around 40 seconds to display the data? This process seems to stall and wait for something

Comment: No, I don't know your other code. Openweathermap is pretty fast. Did you delete the ugly `repeat - while` loop?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, yes I did get rid of the repeat - while loop, and while it does stall a bit,  the main issue I am experiencing now is how it handles the search input, if there is an error finding what I searched for the app crashes, any thoughts as to why?

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Well not exactly, it’s the same problem - the only difference is now I’m using your code and the app doesn’t freeze it crashes.

Comment: Did you change the struct members? Once again: The data returned from the `weather` URL does not match the `WeatherDocument` struct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
makeGetCall()
repeat{
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
} while !done
```

You're only calling `makeGetCall()` once. If it fails, you'll repeat that `RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))` call forever, blocking the main thread. If you want to re-attempt the `makeGetCall` until it works, move it down into the `repeat` block.

It sounds like there's also a decoding issue that will prevent `makeGetCall()` from completing, but I leave that for a separate answer.

Comment: I have added the error message, it should add a bit more to the story

Comment: Let me know your thoughts

Comment: The error is helpful, but doesn't explain why the application is freezing. Can you post the entire class that's calling the `URLSession.shared.dataTask` function?

Comment: Added how the function is called..I think it may have something to do with "RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
    }while !done "

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Ok after adding makeGetCall() into the repeat block, it freezes the application and repeatedly adds prints that same error json message I posted earlier

Comment: Yup, now you'll need to fix the decoding issue. In general though, you shouldn't block the main thread.

Comment: What can be done about the decoding issue? I really appreciate your help

Comment: See vadian's comment on the the question

Comment: The completion handler now causes the Xcode to breakpoint at (see updated post)